# How to code sign and run installer on hosted environment?

Tags: azure-devops, inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

I have a VS2019 project that code signs using Windows 10 Kit's `SignTool.exe`, and builds an installer using Inno Setup. This is part of the projects `PostBuildEvent`. How would I do this properly in a hosted DevOps Build pipeline?

The project file's `PostBuildEvent` is below:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
        if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" "$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\SignTool.exe" sign /n "SomeCompanyName" /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /td SHA256 $(TargetDir)Test1.*.dll $(TargetDir)Test1.exe
        if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" "%25ProgramFiles(x86)%25\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" "$(SolutionDir)Setup\Setup.iss"
    </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have a DevOps build pipeline that is using a "Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019" agent pool, it has "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763".

I could create a command line task to invoke the `SignTool.exe` using an updated path.  How do I handle the Inno setup installer?

Comment: Is Inno Setup installed on the hosted agent? If not, can you install it via some sort of package manager? If the answer is "no", then you can't use the hosted agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I handle the Inno setup installer?

You could install Inno Setup via **Chocolatey** during building on hosted agent.

The [VS2019 image](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md) has `Chocolatey 0.10.11` installed on it, this should a good way to install tools during a build if you can find your tool as a package there.

Besides, Inno Setup does support being installed via Chocolatey. You can see that on the packages page [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/inno-script-studio). That green bulb at the top of the page is an indication that this package version correctly installed via the automated processes that Chocolatey has, verifying that a package installed correctly.

You can check the ticket [Add Inno Setup to Visual Studio 2017 Images](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/261) on Github for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is correct, Inno Setup is already installed on the VS2019 image. I ran Chocolately to install Inno Setup and it said `- innosetup - InnoSetup v5.6.1.20190126 already installed.`